# How to stop the python script

Tags: python, linux, unix

I am trying to write a python script that also deals killing/stopping its own process with the signals.

It runs each files one at a time, sleep at specific time and run again until it finished the whole directory with files. The processing time of each file is around 5 to 10 minutes depending on the size.

However, I want my program to stop when I give the signal. It should not kill it right away. It should run the current file and stop afterwards.

So I cannot use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> because it suspends the pid right away.

```
stop = False
def handler(number, frame):
    global stop
    stop = True
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler)
while not stop:
    # Do things
```

Above is what I tried, but it kills it right away when I signal. Also it goes into an infinite loop even after it finishes working on all the files.

What can I do to stop the process when I signal, allowing it to finish processing the current file first?

Comment: Have you tried to catch SIGTERM instead SIGUSR1?

Comment: I suspect the infinite loop depends on the condition you put in your `while` statement. If you do not send the USR1 signal, there is nothing telling your program to exit the loop. The `for` loop (with the `break` inside) proposed by jsbueno in his answer is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install a signal handler for signal.SIGTERM - and within it setup a state variable in your program that you check when finishing processing each file.

It is actually quite simple - see the documentation at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html .

```
import os 
import signal
terminate = False

for filename in os.listdir("<your dir>"):
    if terminate:
       break
    process_next_file(filename)

def handler(signum, frame):
    global terminate
    print("Termination requested")
    terminate = True

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
```

(Also, you can use other signals - SIGINT is the one used when the user press ctrl+C for example)

Comment: isnt this exactly same as what I did? this goes into the infinite loop and kills it right away instead of waiting for a file to finish

Comment: Yes . sorry   - this is the same you did but for using "SIGTERM".  But on the test I did here, it did work. As for the infinite loop, I will update the answer

Comment: how do I kill it using your coding? is it kill -SIGTERM PID?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a command listener thread. Main thread still does file processing. For example, the listener thread waits a command from standard input. When you send "stop" command, it sets a varible. The file processor thread checks the variable before processing a file. So, it can stop when you want to stop processing.